# Return at most 100 equally spaced rows from query

Tags: postgresql, time, sample

I have a table with time series data that looks like this:

| id | pressure | date | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 873d8bc5-46fe-4d92-bb3b-4efeef3f1e8e | 1.54 | 1999-01-08 04:05:06 | "London" |
| c47c89f1-bdf8-420c-9237-32d70f9119f6 | 1.67 | 1999-01-08 04:05:06 | "Paris" |
| 54bbd56b-3269-4417-8422-3f1b7285e165 | 1.77 | 1999-01-08 04:05:06 | "Berlin" |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Now I would like to create a query for a given location between 2 dates that returns at most 100 results. If its less or equal than 100, simply return all the rows. If its more than 100, I'd like it to equally space them by date.

(ie if I select from 1.January 1970 to 1.January 2020 theres 18,993 days, so I'd like it to skip every 189th day so it returns exactly 100 records (cutting off the remaining 93 days).

So it returns rows like this:

| id | pressure | date | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 873d8bc5-46fe-4d92-bb3b-4efeef3f1e8e | 1.54 | 1970-01-01 04:05:06 | London |
| 8dc7c77b-6958-4cc7-914a-4b9c1f661200 | 1.1 | 1970-07-09 04:05:06 | London |
| 4e3d4c3b-a7e3-48bf-b6a3-5327cc606c82 | 1.23 | 1971-01-14 04:05:06 | London |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

heres how far I got:

```
SELECT 
   pressure,
   date 
FROM 
   location
WHERE
   location=$1
   date>$2 AND date<$3
ORDER BY
   date
```

The problem is, I see no way of achieving this without first loading all the rows, counting them and then sampling them out, which would be bad for perfomance (which means I'd have to load 18993 rows to return 100). So is there a way to efficiently load those hundred rows as you go?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you could provide the exact expected result of minimal reproducible example (preferably in a fiddle). Why wouldn't a `LIMIT 100` work in this case? Sorry if I'm oversimplifying.

Comment: Limit just gets the first 100 results and discards the rest. I want a subsample of all results that have equal distance to each other. I cant make a fiddle since its a postgres question. but I can provide a concrete example

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but some ideas to start one:

- `SELECT MAX(date), MIN(date) FROM location` gets you the first and last dates
- something like `SELECT MIN(date)::timestamp as beginning, (MAX(date)::timestamp - MIN(date)::timestamp)/COUNT(*) as avgdistance FROM location` (no guarantee on syntax, can't check on a live DB right now) would get you the start point and the average distance between points.
- The method to get every nth row is `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, row_number() over() rn FROM tab) foo WHERE foo.rn % {n} = 0;` (with {n} replaced by your desired number).
- You can probably replace that WHERE with something else than a row_number() check and that will get you somewhere.

Feel free to delete this answer if a real answer comes along, until then maybe this'll get you started.